# Crear materiales propios a objetos desde Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender

Gente, lo que quiero es crear materiales propios a cada objeto para así al momento de modificar alguna propiedad del material no lo haga en más de un objeto. Lo que sucede es que todos los materiales creados los asigna a solo un objeto, el primero en ser creado, y no entiendo porque. Anexo código en python para ser ejecutado desde blender para mas claridad. Espero una respuesta y muchas gracias.

Otra solución podría ser crear un objeto con un solo material y duplicarlo para que todos tengan material, pero cuando modifico una propiedad del material como podría desvincularlos para que no lo modifique en todos los objetos sino solo uno en específico.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=1, location=(-1,-2,0))
nombre = "C1"
bpy.context.object.name = nombre

objetoActivo = bpy.context.active_object
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name ='material')
objetoActivo.data.materials.append(mat)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=1, location=(1,2,0))
nombre = "C2"
bpy.context.object.name = nombre
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name ='material1')
objetoActivo.data.materials.append(mat)
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `objetoActivo` siempre hace referencia al primer objeto que creas, referencia asignada en `objetoActivo = bpy.context.active_object` y que posteriormente nunca reasignas. Por eso con  `objetoActivo.data.materials.append(mat)` siempre agregas el material al mismo objeto.

Puedes reasignar la el valor de `objetoActivo` trás crear el segundo objeto mediante `objetoActivo = bpy.context.active_object`  o directamente:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=1, location=(-1,-2,0))
nombre = "C1"
bpy.context.object.name = nombre
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name ='material')
bpy.context.object.data.materials.append(mat)


bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=1, location=(1,2,0))
nombre = "C2"
bpy.context.object.name = nombre
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name ='material1')
bpy.context.object.data.materials.append(mat)
```